# Can you deploy to Elastic Beanstalk from Cloud9?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloud9

If I have some code, such as `HTML` and `PHP` files, in a `Cloud9` instance, can I deploy this directly to an `Elastic Beanstalk` instance?

Or do I have to download the files from `Cloud9` to my computer and then upload them to `Elastic Beanstalk`?

Comment: It should be possible. Clound9 has was cli so you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, Elastic Beanstalk environments are deployed from S3 buckets by the underlying CloudFormation stack, so the first step in the deployment process will be copying files into a newly created [bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.S3.html).

You can initiate this process from any properly configured machine, virtual or otherwise.  An instance running Cloud9 generally meets these criteria.